# Inherit a custom interface which itself inherits IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>

Tags: c#, class, generics, inheritance

How should I make my class "MyDict" take KeyValuePair<GKey, GValue>> as parameter when it inherits from the IDict<KeyValuePair<GKey, GValue>>. Basically I want to be able to create a custom implementation of a the Dictionary collection which can retrieve/add items by key/value.

```
    public interface IDict<TKey, TValue> : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
    {
        public TKey Get(TKey param);
        public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> keyValuePair);
    }

    public class MyDict<GKey, GValue> : IDict<KeyValuePair<GKey, GValue>> 
    {
        public GKey Key { get; set; }
        public GValue Value { get; set; }
        public MyDict<GKey, GValue> Dictionary { get; set; }

        public MyDict()
        {
            Dictionary = new MyDict<GKey, GValue>();
        }

        public void Add(GKey key, GValue value)
        {
            Dictionary.Add(new KeyValuePair<GKey, GValue>(key, value));
        }

        public void Add(KeyValuePair<GKey, GValue> keyValuePair)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

As you can see I've tried this and it doesn't work. I tried other solutions and still nothing worked.

Comment: Did you try the obvious `MyDict<TKey, TValue> : IDict<TKey, TValue>`? Your `IDict<TKey, TValue>` has two type parameters: the type of the key used to look up the value, and the type of value associated with a key.

Comment: How is you implementation different from a regular dictionary?

Comment: I did that works but I don't think it would count as a keyvaluepair this way. I want to be able to let's say get a value by key and the other way around.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "get a value by key *and the other way around*". When you want to use a key to look up a value in your `MyDict`, what type does the key have, and what type does the value have?

Comment: If you describe what your custom dictionary should be able to do that a regular can not perhaps we can help you with that,

Comment: I meant to say that I want to create a Dictionary-like interface that has all the features of a dictionary but the implementation is mine. That's all.

Comment: You interface can just inherit from IDictionary<TKey, Value> and then you can just add your own features in your interface and you will get all the default ones from inheritance.

Comment: I would note that the example code is all kinds of wrong. Interface is not implemented, the constructor seem to cause infinite recursion, seem to mix up a dictionary and dictionary value etc.

Comment: @JonasH Um yeah I kind of realized it too because it gives a stack overflow at runtime.. That's whatever but still I was kind of confused, but I got everything right now so yeah. Thanks for the help everyone, really appreciate it!